# Were the snow-elves evil?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I am considering using Wuuthraad. However, from the lore I could gather, Ysgramor seems to be a genocidal megalomaniac - and his weapon killed the snow elves by the droves and led to their descent into the Falmer.

But if they were evil, I have no problems using it (it does look nice).

So, any lore that tells us of the nature of snow elves?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One could say they were evil, as they've launched a seemingly unprovoked attack on the nord city of Saarthal, known as the Night of Tears, slaying everybody in the city, after which they were soundly crushed by Ysgramor and his Companions, whom he brought from Atmora. They then were poisoned by the Dwemer, who offered them refuge underground. They were made to eat poisonous mushrooms that made them blind and became a necessary part of their diet, ensuring they would forever remain so.

Of course, history is written by the victor, and the attack on Saarthal may not have been as unprovoked as the books suggest. Not to mention the fact that Nords are a rather eccentric bunch who came to settle Tamriel uninvited by its inhabitants.

Comment: Very well, since I have a justification, even if it's a bit vague because the poor elves were not around to tell what really happened, I can now use Wuthraad without my conscience making grating noises :)

Comment: I don't think all the snow elves were evil. It wasn't the whole race that massacred the city, yet all of them paid the price.